# contains() method present in java.lang.String doesnot behave properly for some scenarios,Could anyone please explain this behavior

Tags: java, string

I am trying to verify a scenario wherein i am trying to check if one `String` contains another `String` using the `contains(CharSequence s)` method present `java.lang.String` package.

```
String s1 = "AQUAFRESH";
String s2 = "AF";

if(s1.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase())){
    System.out.println("S1 contains S2");
}
else{
    System.out.println("S1 doesnot contains S2");
}
```

produces output as **S1 contains S2**,

Can anyone explain why this kind of behavior occurs.

Thanks.

Comment: And where is the problem? It works as expected...

Comment: `AQU-AF-RESH` So whats the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not weird behaviour. See your code.

`s1 = "AQUAFRESH"` s1.toLowerCase() will return "aquafresh"

`s2 = "AF"` s2.toLowerCase() will return "af".

Now s1.contains(s2) will return true because `aqu **af** resh` contains `af` string.

Answer (score 1):

aqu'af'resh contains 'af'. where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method do

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Your `AQUAFRESH`  have `AF`

```
       ^^
```

You might missed that inbetween there is `AF`, What you are seeing might be **A**QUA**F**RESH

Comment: Thanks i observe it now.i had missed it in a hurry.

Comment: @SrivatsaVinay That's fine. Happens.

Comment: If i need to achieve the same using regular expressions,how do i do it.

Comment: @SrivatsaVinay On which basic you are going to recognize the both letters ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's rather simple. You have 2 Strings

"AQUAFRESH"
"AF"

and there's really `AF` in `AQU **AF** RESF`.

Answer (score 0):

So whats wrong? aqu**AF**resh really contains AF

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue here. `contains()` check whether something you put in side bracket is there in the considering `String`.

"consideringString".contains("someThing")